# ladder rests against the top of a perpendicular wall

Tags: trigonometry

A ladder rests against the top of a perpendicular wall of a building and makes an angle of $73^{\circ}$ with the ground. If the foot of the ladder is $2$ m from the wall.

Calculate:

- The height of the building,
- The length of the ladder

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let The height of the building be $x$ m and The length of the ladder be $y$ m.

Then apply that $\cos \theta$ is base/hypotenuse and $\tan \theta$ is perpendicular/base.

Here $\theta = 73^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 2):

In following diagram.

[image: page 1]

Let AB length of the ladder. BC length of the wall of building and AC = 2m distance b/w foot of the ladder and wall.

And $\theta = 73°$

$\tan \theta = \frac{BC}{AC}$

Put values and find BC.

$\cos \theta = \frac{AC}{AB}$

Put values and find AB.